# How to switch to production mode for serverless development in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I use `angular-mock` for development. And I use `webpack`.
I need help for organizing toggle between production and development mode.
And sorry for my English.

```js
angular.module('userModule', ['userModuleMock'])
  .factory('userService', userService);

userService.$inject = ['$http'];

function userService($http) {
  return {
    getAll: function() {
      return $http.get('/api/v1/users');
    }
  };
}

angular.module('userModuleMock', ['ngMockE2E'])
  .run(userServiceMock);

userServiceMock.$inject = ['$httpBackend'];

function userServiceMock($httpMock) {
    var users = [
      {
        name: 'John'
      },
      {
        name: 'Mary'
      }
    ];
    $httpMock.whenGET('/api/v1/users').respond(users);
}

angular.module('app', ['userModule'])
  .controller('appController', appController);

appController.$inject = ['userService'];

function appController(userService) {
  userService.getAll()
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      throw err;
    });
}

angular.bootstrap(
  document.getElementById('root'),
  ['app']
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/angular-mocks@1.7.6/angular-mocks.js"></script>

<div id="root">
  <div ng-controller="appController"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't get the question

Comment: @PierreEmmanuelLallemant, how to switch off mock data for production mode? I need that my app gets data from real backend instead mock